# Docker pyqtwebengine gives error module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a docker file like below. We did not do any change to it. It worked till recent.

```
    FROM ubuntu:20.04 as ubuntupyqt
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN adduser --quiet --disabled-password qtuser && usermod -a -G video qtuser
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install alsa -y \
    && apt-get install libnss3 -y \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pyqt5 \
    && apt-get install python3-pip -y \
    && pip3 install --default-timeout=900 pyqtwebengine

FROM ubuntupyqt as stage-ubuntu

ARG ARG_VCS_REF
ARG ARG_VERSION_STICKER

LABEL \
    maintainer="https://github.com/accetto" \
    vendor="accetto" \
    version-sticker="${ARG_VERSION_STICKER}" \
    org.label-schema.vcs-ref="${ARG_VCS_REF}" \
    org.label-schema.vcs-url="https://github.com/accetto/ubuntu-vnc-xfce"

### 'apt-get clean' runs automatically
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        inetutils-ping \
        lsb-release \
        net-tools \
        unzip \
        vim \
        zip \
        curl \
        git \
        wget \
        nano
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

### install current 'jq' explicitly
RUN \
    { \
    JQ_VERSION="1.6" ; \
    JQ_DISTRO="jq-linux64" ; \
    cd /tmp ; \
    wget -q "https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-${JQ_VERSION}/${JQ_DISTRO}" ; \
    wget -q "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/sig/v${JQ_VERSION}/sha256sum.txt" ; \
    test=$(grep "${JQ_DISTRO}" sha256sum.txt | sha256sum -c | grep -c "${JQ_DISTRO}: OK") ; \
    if [ $test -ne 1 ] ; then \
        echo "FAILURE: ${JQ_DISTRO} failed checksum test" ; \
        exit 1 ; \
    else \
        rm sha256sum.txt ; \
        chown root "${JQ_DISTRO}" ; \
        chmod +x "${JQ_DISTRO}" ; \
        # mv -f "${JQ_DISTRO}" $(which jq) ; \
        mv -f "${JQ_DISTRO}" /usr/bin/jq ; \
    fi ; \
    cd - ; \
    }

### next ENTRYPOINT command supports development and should be overriden or disabled
### it allows running detached containers created from intermediate images, for example:
### docker build --target stage-vnc -t dev/ubuntu-vnc-xfce:stage-vnc .
### docker run -d --name test-stage-vnc dev/ubuntu-vnc-xfce:stage-vnc
### docker exec -it test-stage-vnc bash
# ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

FROM stage-ubuntu as stage-xfce

ENV \
    LANG='en_US.UTF-8' \
    LANGUAGE='en_US:en' \
    LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

### 'apt-get clean' runs automatically
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        mousepad \
        locales \
        supervisor \
        xfce4 \
        xfce4-terminal \
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
    && apt-get purge -y \
        pm-utils \
        xscreensaver* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

FROM stage-xfce as stage-vnc

### 'apt-get clean' runs automatically
### installed into '/usr/share/usr/local/share/vnc'
### Bintray has been deprecated and disabled since 2021-05-01
# RUN wget -qO- https://dl.bintray.com/tigervnc/stable/tigervnc-1.10.1.x86_64.tar.gz | tar xz --strip 1 -C /
# RUN wget -qO- https://github.com/accetto/tigervnc/releases/download/v1.10.1-mirror/tigervnc-1.10.1.x86_64.tar.gz | tar xz --strip 1 -C /
RUN wget -qO- https://sourceforge.net/projects/tigervnc/files/stable/1.10.1/tigervnc-1.10.1.x86_64.tar.gz | tar xz --strip 1 -C /

FROM stage-vnc as stage-novnc

### same parent path as VNC
ENV NO_VNC_HOME=/usr/share/usr/local/share/noVNCdim

### 'apt-get clean' runs automatically
### 'python-numpy' used for websockify/novnc
### ## Use the older version of websockify to prevent hanging connections on offline containers,
### see https://github.com/ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container/issues/50
### installed into '/usr/share/usr/local/share/noVNCdim'
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        python-numpy \
    && mkdir -p ${NO_VNC_HOME}/utils/websockify \
    && wget -qO- https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/archive/v1.2.0.tar.gz | tar xz --strip 1 -C ${NO_VNC_HOME} \
    && wget -qO- https://github.com/novnc/websockify/archive/v0.9.0.tar.gz | tar xz --strip 1 -C ${NO_VNC_HOME}/utils/websockify \
    && chmod +x -v ${NO_VNC_HOME}/utils/*.sh \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

### add 'index.html' for choosing noVNC client
RUN echo \
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n" \
"<html>\n" \
"    <head>\n" \
"        <title>noVNC</title>\n" \
"        <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n" \
"    </head>\n" \
"    <body>\n" \
"        <p><a href=\"vnc_lite.html\">noVNC Lite Client</a></p>\n" \
"        <p><a href=\"vnc.html\">noVNC Full Client</a></p>\n" \
"    </body>\n" \
"</html>" \
> ${NO_VNC_HOME}/index.html

FROM stage-novnc as stage-wrapper

### 'apt-get clean' runs automatically
### Install nss-wrapper to be able to execute image as non-root user
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        gettext \
        libnss-wrapper \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

FROM stage-wrapper as stage-final

LABEL \
    any.accetto.description="Headless Ubuntu VNC/noVNC container with Xfce desktop" \
    any.accetto.display-name="Headless Ubuntu/Xfce VNC/noVNC container" \
    any.accetto.expose-services="6901:http,5901:xvnc" \
    any.accetto.tags="ubuntu, xfce, vnc, novnc"

### Arguments can be provided during build
ARG ARG_HOME
ARG ARG_REFRESHED_AT
ARG ARG_VERSION_STICKER
ARG ARG_VNC_BLACKLIST_THRESHOLD
ARG ARG_VNC_BLACKLIST_TIMEOUT
ARG ARG_VNC_PW
ARG ARG_VNC_RESOLUTION

ENV \
    DISPLAY=:1 \
    HOME=${ARG_HOME:-/home/headless} \
    NO_VNC_PORT="6901" \
    REFRESHED_AT=${ARG_REFRESHED_AT} \
    STARTUPDIR=/dockerstartup \
    VERSION_STICKER=${ARG_VERSION_STICKER} \
    VNC_BLACKLIST_THRESHOLD=${ARG_VNC_BLACKLIST_THRESHOLD:-20} \
    VNC_BLACKLIST_TIMEOUT=${ARG_VNC_BLACKLIST_TIMEOUT:-0} \
    VNC_COL_DEPTH=24 \
    VNC_PORT="5901" \
    VNC_PW=${ARG_VNC_PW:-headless} \
    VNC_RESOLUTION=${ARG_VNC_RESOLUTION:-1360x768} \
    VNC_VIEW_ONLY=false

### Creates home folder
WORKDIR ${HOME}

COPY [ "./src/startup", "${STARTUPDIR}/" ]

### Preconfigure Xfce
COPY [ "./src/home/Desktop", "./Desktop/" ]
COPY [ "./src/home/config/xfce4/panel", "./.config/xfce4/panel/" ]
COPY [ "./src/home/config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml", "./.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/" ]

### 'generate_container_user' has to be sourced to hold all env vars correctly
RUN echo 'source $STARTUPDIR/generate_container_user' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc

### Fix permissions
RUN chmod +x \
        "${STARTUPDIR}/set_user_permissions.sh" \
        "${STARTUPDIR}/vnc_startup.sh" \
        "${STARTUPDIR}/version_of.sh" \
        "${STARTUPDIR}/version_sticker.sh" \
    && gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/hicolor \
    && "${STARTUPDIR}"/set_user_permissions.sh "${STARTUPDIR}" "${HOME}"

EXPOSE ${VNC_PORT} ${NO_VNC_PORT}

USER qtuser
ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR /home/qtuser
ENV QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/Qt/${QT_VERSION}/gcc_64/plugins
ENV DISPLAY=:1


### Issue #7: Mitigating problems with foreground mode
WORKDIR ${STARTUPDIR}
COPY htmlToPdfnew.py /htmltopdf/htmlToPdfnew.py
COPY htmltopdf.sh /htmltopdf/htmltopdf.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/htmltopdf/htmltopdf.sh"]
CMD [ "--wait" ]
```

But now it gives below error

```
Collecting PyQt5>=5.15.4
  Downloading PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpfq1k332v prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpoecmj_rl
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vqo0je_3/PyQt5
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpfq1k332v", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpfq1k332v", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/tmpfq1k332v", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/tmp/tmpfq1k332v", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/tmp/tmpfq1k332v", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pb3adgde/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pb3adgde/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pb3adgde/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-vqo0je_3/PyQt5/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pb3adgde/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pb3adgde/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-pb3adgde/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpfq1k332v prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpoecmj_rl Check the logs for full command output.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y     && apt-get install alsa -y     && apt-get install libnss3 -y     && apt-get install -y python3-pyqt5     && apt-get install python3-pip -y     && pip3 install --upgrade pip     && pip3 install --default-timeout=900 pyqtwebengine' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How to fix above error ?
I tried many solutions from internet.